# Returning a value from within an if statement has a "mismatched types" error

Tags: rust

In the function below, I match the first full character of a `&str`, and if it is a `*`, `-`, or  `_` and if it is those that character is returned, and with the `_` arm I want to check if the character is whitespace, and return `'a'` otherwise.

```
fn print_character(text: &str) {
    let character: char = match text.chars().nth(0).unwrap() {
        ch @ '*' | ch @ '-' | ch @ '_' => ch,
        ch @ _ => {
            if !ch.is_whitespace() {
                return 'a';
            }
            ' '
        }
    };

    println!("{}", character);
}
```

When I run the code I get the error below:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:24
  |
6 |                 return 'a';
  |                        ^^^ expected (), found char
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `char`
```

Comment: Pattern guards are nice too: `ch if ch.is_whitespace() => ' ', _ => 'a'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't want a return here, you're not trying to return from the  function. Just use the `'a'` as an expression. You also need the space char as an else branch, not standing on its own.

```
if !ch.is_whitespace() {
    'a'
} else {
    ' '
}
```

#### Why the `else` is required

`if` is an expression, and it *has* to evaluate to some value. That value needs a definite type; it can't sometimes be a `char` and sometimes something else. If you were to just do this:

```
if !ch.is_whitespace() {
    'a'
}
```

What would the `if` expression evaluate to in case the test fails? Instead of just evaluating to some arbitrary `char` value, the language simply requires an `else` branch. If you don't want to use the `if` as an expression, and just use it for its side-effects, then you can leave out the `else`. In that case, it is still an expression, but its value is `()` (irrespective of whether the test passed or not), and you need to end it with a statement.

Comment: Why does it have to be within an `else` rather than after the `if` statement? I should also say having it just as `'a'` didn't work either without it being within the `else`

Comment: @Aaronepower: Because an if without an else always results in a value of `()`, but you're trying to have it evaluate as a `char`.