# Why is the compiler asking me to add a return statement here?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do the rustlings course and I don't understand the error I'm getting for the following code:

```
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a > b {
        a
    }
    b
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> exercises/if/if1.rs:7:9
  |
6 | /     if a > b {
7 | |         a
  | |         ^ expected `()`, found `i32`
8 | |     }
  | |_____- expected this to be `()`
  |
help: you might have meant to return this value
  |
7 |         return a;
  |         ^^^^^^  ^
```

if I add the return, it *does* work but shouldn't the above also work? If I use an if-else it works also:

```
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a > b {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812469/returning-a-value-from-within-an-if-statement-has-a-mismatched-types-error should answer your question. The if without an else is evaluated as an expression returning () (i.e. void)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a value from within an if statement has a "mismatched types" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812469/returning-a-value-from-within-an-if-statement-has-a-mismatched-types-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Result and if/else/return statements E0308 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049717/result-and-if-else-return-statements-e0308-error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In rust only the ***last expression*** is taken as return value.

In your case:

```rust
if a > b {
    a
}
```

and:

```rust
b
```

are expressions themselves, so which one should it return?
In fact `if` expressions without an `else` clause return `()` in Rust (that is why you get the conflict in types). For more reference refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812469/returning-a-value-from-within-an-if-statement-has-a-mismatched-types-error).

Meanwhile:

```rust
if a > b {
    a
} else {
    b
}
```

is a single expression, whose branches are single expressions too (`a` and `b`). So it is clear that it should return what the inner return of the `if` expressions does.

Also, you can use a ***return statement*** in the `if` expression to help the compiler realize what to do in the first case (From @Cerberus' comments: *`return x` is an expression, too - it just evaluates to never and so can be used everywhere without type mismatch.*):

```rust
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a > b {
        return a;
    }
    b
}
```

Just the last `b` expression would be used as final return (other returns are statements, not expressions).

Comment: Small nitpick: `return x` is an expression, too - it just evaluates to `never` and so can be used everywhere without type mismatch.

Comment: @Cerberus The type of the `return` expression does not matter here, since the trailing semicolon changes the type of an expression to `()`. You can use an expression of an arbitrary type in that place as long as you add the semicolon. The only special thing about the `return` expression being of type `!` is that you could omit the semicolon and it would still compile, but please don't do that. :)

Comment: To be even more precise, the mere _presence_ of the return expression changes the type of the entire block to `!`, so you could use an expression of an arbitrary type after the return expression without a trailing semicolon, and it would still compile.